# When I include Bootsrap Javascript for using button dropdown, my navbar stops working

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, navbar

I had my webpage set up with a normal NavBar using links only and it worked perfectly, then when I added Bootstrap Javascript for button dropdown (not in the navbar) the links in the navbar stopped working.

When I remove the javascript link, the navbar starts working again. Anybody know why?

```
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Bootstrap Javascript -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>




<!-- Navbar -->
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand bg-light justify-content-between">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="navbar-brand">
                    <a href="/"><img src="{% static 'images/Logo Final_SM-Symbol.png' %}" width="50" height="50"></a>
                </li>
                 <li class="nav-item text-center" id="about-us">
                    <a href="{% url 'guide' %}" class="nav-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#"><span class="fas fa-question"></span><span class="d-none d-sm-inline d-xl-block px-1">Guide</span></a>
                 </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <li class="nav-item text-center" id="">
                    <a href="{% url 'lesson_add' %}" class="nav-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#"><span class="fas fa-plus"></span><span class="d-none d-sm-inline d-xl-block px-1">Add Lesson</span></a></li>
                <li class="nav-item text-center" id="">
                    <a href="{% url 'lesson_list' %}" class="nav-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#"><span class="fas fa-list-ol"></span><span class="d-none d-sm-inline d-xl-block px-1">Full Database</span></a></li>
                <li class="nav-item text-center" id="">
                    <a href="{% url 'search_list' %}" class="nav-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#"><span class="fas fa-search"></span><span class="d-none d-sm-inline d-xl-block px-1">Search Database</span></a></li>
                <li class="nav-item text-center" id="">
                    <a href="{% url 'draft_list' %}" class="nav-link"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#"><span class="far fa-check-square"></span><span class="d-none d-sm-inline d-xl-block px-1">Draft List</span></a></li>
                <li class="nav-item text-center" id="">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#"><span class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></span><span class="d-none d-sm-inline d-xl-block px-1">Log Out</span></a></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bootstrap.bundle.min.js should be adding a click event listener to elements with `data-toggle="modal"` that calls `event.preventDefault()` because it is intended to open a modal on the same page and not navigate to a different page.

If the links are not intended to open a modal then you should remove the attributes `data-toggle="modal"` and `data-target="#"` so that they will take you to the url defined in `href`

Comment: Perfect. The data-toggle tag was there from a previous version I was trying out and was redundant in the new code. Removing it worked perfectly. Your answer also explains why the 'home' link using the img still worked when the others had gone dead. Thanks